# Putting check digit in to form ISBN 10

Tags: iphone, ios, integer, nsnumber, isbn

I'm doing a barcode scanner and doing an in-app conversion of ISBN13 to ISBN10. I could now calculate out the check digit for the ISBN 10 but i do not know how to join it back to a 10 digit number.

What i did was to take out the prefixed "978" for the barcode 9780340961391 which then leaves it with 0340961391 and i only take out the 9 digits, leaving out the check digit of 1 for the isbn 13 which is then left with 034096139.

Then i calculate the check digit of isbn10 which is 2. The problem now is how do i add it to 034096139 to form the final ISBN10 of 0340961392? Thanks :)

Comment: Or for an NSNumber, theNSNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[theNSNumber intValue] * 10 + digit];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your ISBN13 is a string and when adding the check digit back to the SBN number, you would not want to affect the 9 digit number. I would suggest:

```
/* SBNString = 034096139 */
NSString *ISBN10 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%u", SBNString, checkDigit];
```

Comment: @Rick Thanks so much it's great :D but may I ask what is the meaning of u in "%@%u"? I understand d is for integers but i can't seem to find what does u stands for.

Comment: @XUESNOW %u and %s are called tokens, which are used to display different datatypes - %s = string, %d = integer, %0 = octal, %x = hexdecimal, %ld = longint, %lld longlongint and so on. For better understanding: %u is like int, unsigned base 10

Comment: @XUESNOW, like what NSPunk mentioned, %u is for unsigned integer, but you can also use %d so long as your check digit is positive. Do note that if your check digit is negative, %d will display a minus(-) sign, %u will display a very big value.

Comment: @NSPunk, note that %@ is for NSString and %s is for C-String. For iOS or cocoa or objective-C, we use %@ most of the time.